# Racket/Scheme: working with structs

Tags: struct, scheme, racket

I have been given a struct to work with:

```
(struct Binding (id (value #:mutable)))
```

This struct represents a variable binding such as `(set! x 3)` where I would expect id = x and value = 3.

How do I create and initialize this struct?  How do I get the values of `id` and `value` and to set the value of `value`?

Comment: Re: textbook request. Have you seen "How To Design Programs"? It's written by the authors of Racket, it's got five stars on Amazon, and best of all, it's available online at htdp.org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> (struct Binding (id (value #:mutable)))
> (define b (Binding 'x 123))
> (Binding-id b)
'x
> (Binding-value b)
123
> (set-Binding-value! b 456)
> (Binding-value b)
456
```

(See also the documentation page on [structs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html).)